# Check if a string starts with current month and year in ADODB

Tags: adodb

How to Achieve that using the if statement:
I want to say if the Field Type is null then put null, if the first 5 character of the note Filed are the current month and current year (MMMYY) then put current anything else put No.

```
"iif(IsNull(T1.[Type]) ,Null ,iif(Cstr(Left(T1.[Note],5)) = Format(Cstr(T1.[Note]),'MMMYY') ,'Current' ,'No')) as [Reclassification] " & _
```